# Can't change font-family in main.css

Tags: python, html, css, django

Currently using Django with bootstrap 4. For whatever reason, I cannot get the font-family to change through my main.css file. I can change other attributes, but font does not seem to work.

If I change the font-family in my other files, it works. I just cannot change it through my main.css.

What am I doing wrong?

base.html

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
...
```

main.css

```
body {
   font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif !important;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You either have 2 options, create a style tag in the head tag or select everything instead of body in main.css. Example:

base.html

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
    <style>
        * {
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif !important;
        }
    </style>
...
```

or

main.css

```css
* {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try:

body style="font-family:Times New Roman, Georgia,serif !important"
Directly in the HTML code

Also, you can try putting the main.css file in the same folder as the HTML file and check if that works.